# AWS - Redshift query editor v2 - export to csv more than 100 rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am currently using AWS redshift editor v2 and wanted to export more than 100 rows to a csv.
Currently I only managed to export the current page of my editor (with is limited at 100 rows per page)

Did someone managed to do that ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this functionality is not available at the moment. In this case, I suggest to either:

- Use another database client (e.g. dbeaver)
- Export query result to s3 and then download it.